# Не получается правильно ввести структуру в файл

Tags: c++

Не получается ввести данные в файл при подключении cin.ignore() почему-то исчезает первый символ первой строки, а без cin.ignore() при втором проходе цикла в fl.n вводится пустое значение. Ещё не получается вывести все строки, выводится только 1 строка.

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <string>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <limits>
    #include <fstream> // <ifstream> — файловый ввод и  <ofstream>  — файловый вывод.
    using namespace std;

    struct FILM {
        char n[256]; // название
        char r[256]; // режиссер
        int g; // год выхода
        int c; // цена
    };

    void form() {
        ofstream film("film.txt"); // создание файла
        int x = 1; // для выхода из цикла, который заполняет файл
        cout << "Введите информацию о 5 фильмах \n";
        FILM fl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            cout << "Фильм №" << i+1 << endl;
            cout << "Введите название фильма:";
            cin.getline(fl.n, 256);
            cout << "Введите режиссера:";
            cin.getline(fl.r, 256);
            cout << "Введите год выпуска:";
            cin >> fl.g;
            cout << "Введите цену на фильм без \"руб\":";
            cin >> fl.c;
            cout << endl;
            film << fl.n << endl;
            film << fl.r << endl;
            film << fl.g << endl;
            film << fl.c << endl;
            film << endl;
        }
        film.close(); // закрытие файла
    }

    void pok() {
        ifstream film("film.txt", ios::binary);
        if (!film.is_open()) // если файл не открыт
            cout << "Файл не открыт!\n"; // сообщить об этом
        else
        {
            int len = 255;
            int str = 25;
            char ch = "\n";
            char mas[len][str];
            for (int i = 0; i < str; i++) {
                film.getline(mas[i], len - 1, ch);  //Считываем строки в массив
                cout << mas[i] << endl; //Выводи строку из массива
            }
        }
        film.close();
    }

    int main() {
        setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
        SetConsoleCP(1251);
        SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // корректное отображение Кириллицы
        form();
        //pok();
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

[image: вывод]

Answer (score 0):

1) Я не помню всех тонкостей, но когда вы используете cin чтобы ввести число, то при вводе числа нажимаете кнопку <kbd>Enter</kbd>, и если сразу после этого начать вводить строку (`cin.getline(...)`) он видит этот перевод строки и считывает его как пустую строку.

Можно решить так (хотя наверняка есть красивое решение и можно вызывать какой-нибудь метод, тот же `cin.ignore()` вместо дополнительного `cin.getline(...)`):

```
bool firstTime = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    cout << "Фильм №" << i+1 << endl;
    cout << "Введите название фильма:";
    if (firstTime){
        firstTime = false;
        cin.getline(fl.n, 256);
    }else{
        cin.getline(fl.n, 256);
        cin.getline(fl.n, 256);
    }
    cout << "Введите режиссера:";
    cin.getline(fl.r, 256);
    cout << "Введите год выпуска:";
    cin >> fl.g;
    cout << "Введите цену на фильм без \"руб\":";
    cin >> fl.c;
    cout << endl;
    film << fl.n << endl;
    film << fl.r << endl;
    film << fl.g << endl;
    film << fl.c << endl;
    film << endl;
}
```

2) Функция `pok()`У меня все строки вывелись, хотя я бы и изменил строки

```
    char ch = "\n";
    char mas[len][str];
```

на

```
    char ch = '\n';
    char mas[str][len];
```